# Error assigning SQLite3 query results into dictionary

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to query for values in my SQLite3 table and store each of those values in a separate dictionary in my python file. However, this returns an error:

```
with sqlite3.connect('database.db') as conn:
        conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        settings = cursor.execute('SELECT nhl, nba, nfl, mlb FROM settings WHERE id = ?', (userID,))
        conn.commit()
    
# Store each individual setting in dict
sports = {
        'nhl': settings[0]['nhl'],
        'nba': settings[0]['nba'],
        'nfl': settings[0]['nfl'],
        'mlb': setttings[0]['mlb']
}
```

I also get an error if I try to do so without row_factory

```
with sqlite3.connect('database.db') as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        settings = cursor.execute('SELECT nhl, nba, nfl, mlb FROM settings WHERE id = ?', (userID,))
        conn.commit()
    
# Store each individual setting in dict
sports = {
        'nhl': settings[0],
        'nba': settings[1],
        'nfl': settings[2],
        'mlb': setttings[3]
}
```

It is to my understanding that using row_factory will return a dict-like data structure? The error I am getting is:

```
TypeError: 'sqlite3.Cursor' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). – Don't forget to accept an answer (tick the check-mark next to an answer) when it answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`settings` is a `sqlite.Cursor` object because that's what `execute` returns. One of the [fetch methods](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone) is required to actually get the data from the database.